# How to manually validate a JWT signature using online tools

Tags: jwt

From what I can understand, it's a straight forward process to validate a `JWT` signature. But when I use some online tools to do this for me, it doesn't match. How can I manually validate a `JWT` signature without using a JWT library? I'm needing a quick method (using available online tools) to demo how this is done.

I created my `JWT` on https://jwt.io/#debugger-io with the below info:

- **Algorithm:** `HS256`
- **Secret:** `hONPMX3tHWIp9jwLDtoCUwFAtH0RwSK6`
- **Header:**

  ```
  {
    "alg": "HS256",
    "typ": "JWT"
  }
  ```
- **Payload:**

  ```
  {
    "sub": "1234567890",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "iat": 1516239022
  }
  ```
- **Verify Signature (section):**

  - Secret value changed to above
  - "Checked" secret base64 encoded (whether this is checked or not, still get a different value)

**JWT:**

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.wDQ2mU5n89f2HsHm1dluHGNebbXeNr748yJ9kUNDNCA
```

---

**Manual `JWT` signature verification attempt:**

Using a **base64UrlEncode calculator** (http://www.simplycalc.com/base64url-encode.php or https://www.base64encode.org/)

**If I:** *(Not actual value on sites, modified to show what the tools would ultimately build for me)*

```
base64UrlEncode("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9") + "." + base64UrlEncode("eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ")
```

**I get:**

```
ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5.ZXlKemRXSWlPaUl4TWpNME5UWTNPRGt3SWl3aWJtRnRaU0k2SWtwdmFHNGdSRzlsSWl3aWFXRjBJam94TlRFMk1qTTVNREl5ZlE=
```

> **NOTE:** there's some confusion on my part if I should be encoding the already encoded values, or use the already encoded values as-is.
>
> (i.e. using `base64UrlEncode("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9") + "." + base64UrlEncode("eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ")` vs `"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ"`).
>
> **Regardless** on which I should do, the end result still doesn't match the signature. I'm leaning towards that I should **NOT** re-encode the encoded value, whether that's true or not.

Then using a **HMAC Generator calculator** (https://codebeautify.org/hmac-generator or https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output)

*(Not actual value on sites, modified to show what the tools would ultimately build for me)*

```
HMACSHA256(
 "ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5.ZXlKemRXSWlPaUl4TWpNME5UWTNPRGt3SWl3aWJtRnRaU0k2SWtwdmFHNGdSRzlsSWl3aWFXRjBJam94TlRFMk1qTTVNREl5ZlE=",
  "hONPMX3tHWIp9jwLDtoCUwFAtH0RwSK6"
)
```

Which gets me:

```
a2de322575675ba19ec272e83634755d4c3c2cd74e9e23c8e4c45e1683536e01
```

And that doesn't match the signature portion of the `JWT`:

`wDQ2mU5n89f2HsHm1dluHGNebbXeNr748yJ9kUNDNCAM` **!=** `a2de322575675ba19ec272e83634755d4c3c2cd74e9e23c8e4c45e1683536e01`

---

**Purpose:**

The reason I'm needing to confirm this is to prove the ability to validate that the `JWT` hasn't been tampered with, without decoding the `JWT`.

My clients web interface doesn't need to decode the `JWT`, so there's no need for them to install a **jwt package** for doing that. They just need to do a simple validation to confirm the `JWT` hasn't been tampered with (however unlikely that may be) before they store the `JWT` for future API calls.

Comment: Maybe your problem is just that you encode an already encoded value : `base64UrlEncode("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9")`. The string "eyJh..." is already the result of encoding `{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}`, so to encode it again makes no sense.

Comment: @jps that's a good point, and one I verified didn't change anything if I encode it again or not, either way the signature is incorrect. Reading up on instructions makes it sound like I need to `base64UrlEncode` the value already in the JWT, ultimately encoding it twice... though I'm starting to lean towards not needing to encode it the 2nd time. I'll add this note in the question for clarification, thank you.

Comment: It's always only one time encoding. In `base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload)` payload and header refer to the readable JSON.

Comment: I'll agree with you there @jps. I wish this fixed the issue, I added a note about this in the question.

Comment: I just tried the online HMAC tools (which I didn't know before) and also had a different result than I got on jwt.io. I'm also surprised and right now can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if jwt.io is doing their signature wrong... or appending to the secret I specify, which would cause this.

Comment: @jps Your answer makes sense, but didn't match the signature I was trying to initially validate. I just unchecked the jwt.io checkbox for "secret base64 encoded" and confirmed your logic matches. (seems that checkbox doesn't use the secret, as the signature reverts to the initial signature value when you don't specify a secret). Thank you for helping me figure this out!

Comment: Glad to help. It's an interesting question and I also learned something.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's all a matter of formats and encoding.

On https://jwt.io you get this token based on your input values and secret:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.3pIaKksiX9Zv8Jg-hWbrD24VhL36hBIFaNpA4fVx29M
```

We want to prove that the signature:

```
3pIaKksiX9Zv8Jg-hWbrD24VhL36hBIFaNpA4fVx29M
```

is correct.

The signature is a HMAC-SHA256 hash that is Base64url encoded.
(as described in [RFC7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-7.1))

When you use the [online HMAC generator](https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output) to calculate a hash for

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ
```

with the secret

```
hONPMX3tHWIp9jwLDtoCUwFAtH0RwSK6
```

you get

```
de921a2a4b225fd66ff0983e8566eb0f6e1584bdfa84120568da40e1f571dbd3
```

as result, which is a HMAC-SHA256 value, but not Base64url encoded. This hash is a hexadecimal string representation of a large number.

To compare it with the value from https://jwt.io you need to convert the value from it's hexadecimal string representation back to a number and Base64url encode it.

The following script is doing that and also uses crypto-js to calculate it's own hash. This can also be a way for you to verify without JWT libraries.

```java-script
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

// the input values
var base64Header = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9";
var base64Payload = "eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ";
var secret = "hONPMX3tHWIp9jwLDtoCUwFAtH0RwSK6";

// two hashes from different online tools
var signatureJWTIO = "3pIaKksiX9Zv8Jg-hWbrD24VhL36hBIFaNpA4fVx29M";
var onlineCaluclatedHS256 =  "de921a2a4b225fd66ff0983e8566eb0f6e1584bdfa84120568da40e1f571dbd3";

// hash calculation with Crypto-JS. 
// The two replace expressions convert Base64 to Base64url format by replacing 
// '+' with '-', '/' with '_' and stripping the '=' padding
var base64Signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(base64Header + "." + base64Payload , secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64).replace(/\+/g,'-').replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\=+$/m,'');

// converting the online calculated value to Base64 representation
var base64hash = new Buffer.from(onlineCaluclatedHS256, 'hex').toString('base64').replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-').replace(/\=+$/m,'')


// the results:
console.log("Signature from JWT.IO             : " + signatureJWTIO);
console.log("NodeJS calculated hash            : " + base64Signature);
console.log("online calulated hash (converted) : " + base64hash);
```

The results are:

```
Signature from JWT.IO             : 3pIaKksiX9Zv8Jg-hWbrD24VhL36hBIFaNpA4fVx29M

NodeJS calculated hash            : 3pIaKksiX9Zv8Jg-hWbrD24VhL36hBIFaNpA4fVx29M

online calulated hash (converted) : 3pIaKksiX9Zv8Jg-hWbrD24VhL36hBIFaNpA4fVx29M
```

identical!

Conclusion:

The values calculated by the different online tools are all correct but not directly comparable due to different formats and encodings.
A little script as shown above might be a better solution.

Comment: Istn't the point of checking the JWT issued by an Identity Management System that you do not need to know the IDM's secret key? How do I verify the signature using only the public key?

Comment: The question was about the HS256 algorithm, which does not have private/public (asymmetric) keys but uses the same secret for signing and verification. For asymmetric algorithms (e.g. RS256 there are many answers on this site, depending on programming language, algorithm etc., but nothing I could answer in a comment. If you can't find an answer for your specific case, ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks @jps, I wasn't aware of HS256.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem until I figured out that I was using plain `base64` encoding instead of `base64url`.
There are also some minor details in between.
Here is the step-by-step manual that will, hopefully, make the whole process much more clear.

## Notes

**Note 1:** You must remove all spaces and newlines from your JSON strings (header and payload).
It is implicitly done on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) when you generate a JWT token.

**Note 2:** To convert JSON string to `base64url` string on cryptii.com create the following configuration:

```
First view: Text

Second view: Encode
    Encoding: Base64
    Variant: Standard 'base64url' (RFC 4648 §5)

Third view: Text
```

**Note 3:** To convert HMAC HEX code (signature) to `base64url` string on cryptii.com create the following configuration:

```
First view: Bytes
    Format: Hexadecimal
    Group by: None

Second view: Encode
    Encoding: Base64
    Variant: Standard 'base64url' (RFC 4648 §5)

Third view: Text
```

## Manual

You are going to need only two online tools:

1. **[Tool 1]:** [cryptii.com](https://cryptii.com) - for `base64url` encoding,
2. **[Tool 2]:** [codebeautify.org](https://codebeautify.org/hmac-generator) - for HMAC calculation.

On [cryptii.com](https://cryptii.com) you can do both `base64url` encoding/decoding and also HMAC calculation, but for HMAC you need to provide a HEX key which is different from the input on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io), so I used a separate service for HMAC calculation.

### Input data

In this manual I used the following data:

- Header:

  ```
  {"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}
  ```
- Payload:

  ```
  {"sub":"1234567890","name":"John Doe","iat":1516239022}
  ```
- Secret (key):

  ```
  The Earth is flat!
  ```

The secret is not `base64` encoded.

### Step 1: Convert header [Tool 1]

- Header (plain text):

  ```
  {"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}
  ```
- Header (`base64url` encoded):

  ```
  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
  ```

### Step 2: Convert payload [Tool 1]

- Payload (plain text):

  ```
  {"sub":"1234567890","name":"John Doe","iat":1516239022}
  ```
- Payload (`base64url` encoded):

  ```
  eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ
  ```

### Step 3: Calculate HMAC code (signature) [Tool 2]

Calculate HMAC using `SHA256` algorithm.

- Input string (`base64url` encoded header and payload, concatenated with a dot):

  ```
  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ
  ```
- Calculated code (HEX number):

  ```
  c8a9ae59f3d64564364a864d22490cc666c74c66a3822be04a9a9287a707b352
  ```

The calculated HMAC code is a HEX representation of the signature. 
**Note:** it should not be encoded to `base64url` as a plain text string but as a sequence of bytes.

### Step 4: Encode calculated HMAC code to `base64url` [Tool 1]:

- Signature (Bytes):

  ```
  c8a9ae59f3d64564364a864d22490cc666c74c66a3822be04a9a9287a707b352
  ```
- Signature (`base64url` encoded):

  ```
  yKmuWfPWRWQ2SoZNIkkMxmbHTGajgivgSpqSh6cHs1I
  ```

### Summary

Here are our results (all `base64url` encoded):

- Header:

  ```
  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
  ```
- Payload:

  ```
  eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ
  ```
- Signature:

  ```
  yKmuWfPWRWQ2SoZNIkkMxmbHTGajgivgSpqSh6cHs1I
  ```

The results from [jwt.io](https://jwt.io):

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.yKmuWfPWRWQ2SoZNIkkMxmbHTGajgivgSpqSh6cHs1I
```

As you can see, all three parts are identical.

Comment: +1 for "The calculated HMAC code is a HEX representation of the signature. Note: it should not be encoded to base64url as a plain text string but as a sequence of bytes."