# Manually calculating JWT signature never outputs the real signature

Tags: jwt, language-agnostic

I've been reading a lot of questions on stackOverflow and jwt's docs.
Right now from what I understand this is what I should do to calculate a token:

```
header =
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}

payload =
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "JohnDoe",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
secret = "test123"
```

1. Remove unnecessary spaces and breaklines from header and payload and then encoding both to base64url.

```
base64urlEncode(header)
// output: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
base64urlEncode(payload)
// output: eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG5Eb2UiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTYyMzkwMjJ9
```

Same output as on jwt.io, perfect.

2. Calculate the sha256 hmac using "test123" as secret.

```
sha256_hmac("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG5Eb2UiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTYyMzkwMjJ9", "test123)
// output: 3b59324118bcd59a5435194120c2cfcb7cf295f25a79149b79145696329ffb95
```

3. Convert the hash to string and then base64url encode it.

I use [hex to string converter](https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter) for this part, then I encode it using [base64urlEncode](https://base64.guru/standards/base64url/encode) and I get the following output:
`O1kyQRjCvMOVwppUNRlBIMOCw4_Di3zDssKVw7JaeRTCm3kUVsKWMsKfw7vClQ`

Output from jwt.io
`O1kyQRi81ZpUNRlBIMLPy3zylfJaeRSbeRRWljKf-5U`

But if I go to this page [From Hex, to Base64](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Hex('Auto')To_Base64('A-Za-z0-9-_')&input=M2IgNTkgMzIgNDEgMTggYmMgZDUgOWEgNTQgMzUgMTkgNDEgMjAgYzIgY2YgY2IgN2MgZjIgOTUgZjIgNWEgNzkgMTQgOWIgNzkgMTQgNTYgOTYgMzIgOWYgZmIgOTU) I get the correct output:
`O1kyQRi81ZpUNRlBIMLPy3zylfJaeRSbeRRWljKf-5U`

So what am I doing wrong? Why converting the hex to string and then Encoding it outputs a different result?

In case the online hex to string conversion is wrong, how can I convert this hex to string (so then I can encode it) on c++ without using any libray. Am I correct if I convert each byte (2 characters because hex = 4 bits) to ASCII character and then encode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The general problem here is that the hash is a large number which is only represented as a prinbtable hex code. When you convert this back with the online tool you mentioned you basically get non printable characters which you copy to the base64 converter. And then you depend on the codepage settings from 2 different websites. It's much easier to deal with inside a programm and convert the hash to a byte arry. All explained and shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121763/how-to-manually-validate-a-jwt-signature-using-online-tools/50153299#50153299)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hmac step is correct, does have the right output bytes (as commented).  The conversion problem you have is caused by non-display chars in the temporary string (the raw bytes were not correctly copied pasted from first webpage to second).

To reproduce the exact output at each stage, you can use these commands below.

In terms of C++, you should try to operate on the raw bytes, rather than on the hex string.  Take the raw bytes and run them through a base64 URL-safe encoder.  Or, as in the example below, take the raw bytes, run them through a plain base64 encoder, and then fix the generated base64 string to be URL safe.

1. Construct the header

```
jwt_header=$(echo -n '{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}' | base64 | sed s/\+/-/g | sed 's/\//_/g' | sed -E s/=+$//)

# ans: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
```

2. Construct the payload

```
payload=$(echo -n '{"sub":"1234567890","name":"JohnDoe","iat":1516239022}' | base64 | sed s/\+/-/g |sed 's/\//_/g' |  sed -E s/=+$//)

# ans: eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG5Eb2UiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTYyMzkwMjJ9
```

3. Raw password

```
secret="test123"
```

4. Convert secret to hex (not base64)

```
hexsecret=$(echo -n "$secret" | xxd -p | tr -d '\n')

# ans: 74657374313233
```

5. Perform hmac, and capture the raw bytes (caution, this is a non printable string)

```
hmac_signature_rawbytes=$(echo -n "${jwt_header}.${payload}" |  openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:$hexsecret -binary)
```

6. Dump the raw bytes as hex, for illustration only (matches OP output)

```
echo -n ${hmac_signature_rawbytes} | xxd -p | tr -d '\n'

#ans: 3b59324118bcd59a5435194120c2cfcb7cf295f25a79149b79145696329ffb95
```

7. For JWT signature, convert raw bytes to base64uri encoding

```
hmac_signature=$(echo -n ${hmac_signature_rawbytes} | base64  | sed s/\+/-/g | sed 's/\//_/g' | sed -E s/=+$//)

#ans: O1kyQRi81ZpUNRlBIMLPy3zylfJaeRSbeRRWljKf-5U
```

8. Create the full token

```
jwt="${jwt_header}.${payload}.${hmac_signature}"

# ans: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG5Eb2UiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTYyMzkwMjJ9.O1kyQRi81ZpUNRlBIMLPy3zylfJaeRSbeRRWljKf-5U
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't able to use internet until now. Thanks for the answer, it worked!