# Encode JWT token in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, jwt, token

I want to use a JWT to inatialise a meeting room in Jitsi.
Our software will create the correct url for the user so it can join the meeting.
Only users with the correct token can start a meeting.

The url is created with pl/sql. For the example of a valid token i use the website jwt.io.
I wrote the following code to create the token.
The first part of the token is correct. Only the signature doesn't match. I think i'm missing a typecast or variable l_content has the wrong type.
What am i doing wrong?

```
                    l_token varchar2(30000);
                    l_header varchar2(1000);
                    l_header_base64  raw (1000);

                    l_payload varchar2(10000);
                    l_payload_base64  raw(10000);

                    l_signature varchar2(30000);
                    l_secretkey string(32767) :='your-256-bit-secret';
                    l_content string(32767);
                                    l_content_raw raw(30000);
                    l_point raw(1);

                    l_charset varchar2(8) := 'AL32UTF8';
                    l_crlf varchar2(2) := chr(13) || chr(10);

                    l_pay_clean varchar2(10000);
                    l_hdr_clean varchar2(10000);



        begin
            sys.dbms_output.put_line('Token from JWT.io: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c');
            l_point := utl_i18n.string_to_raw( '.', l_charset);
            --
                    --
                    -- maak header middels json en base64 encode
                    select json_object ('alg'  value 'HS256'
                                       ,'typ'  value 'JWT')
                    into   l_header
                    from dual;

                    select json_object ('sub'  value '1234567890'
                                        ,'name'  value 'John Doe'
                                        ,'iat'  value 1516239022)
                    into   l_payload
                    from dual;

                     l_header_base64  := utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_header));
                     l_payload_base64 := utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_payload));

                    l_hdr_clean := replace(replace(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(l_header_base64),l_crlf), '==');
                    l_pay_clean := replace(replace(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(l_payload_base64),l_crlf), '==');
                    sys.dbms_output.put_line('l_hdr_clean: ' || l_hdr_clean);
                    sys.dbms_output.put_line('l_pay_clean: ' || l_pay_clean);

                    l_content  := l_hdr_clean || '.' ||l_pay_clean;
                    sys.dbms_output.put_line('l_content: ' || l_content);

                    l_signature  := dbms_crypto.mac(UTL_I18N.string_to_raw(l_content, l_charset)
                                                    ,dbms_crypto.hmac_sh256
                                                    ,utl_i18n.string_to_raw(l_secretkey, l_charset));

                    sys.dbms_output.put_line('l_signature:' || l_signature);

                    return l_hdr_clean||'.'||l_pay_clean||'.'||l_signature;
        end;
```

Comment: how does the signature look like? I don't know if this already solves the problem, but at least you need to base64url encode the signature too.

Comment: The signature is like this now: 49F94AC7044948C78A285D904F87F0A4C7897F7E8F3A4EB2255FDA750B2CC397 and it should be this: SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c

If i add the base64 encode to te result of the mac it doesn't work either, or is this not what you mean?

utl_encode.base64_encode(dbms_crypto.mac(UTL_I18N.string_to_raw(l_content, l_charset)
                                                        ,dbms_crypto.hmac_sh256
                                                        ,utl_i18n.string_to_raw(l_secretkey, l_charset)));

Comment: That's a hexadecimal representation of the hash. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50153299/7329832), basically the same problem, just different languages involved. What you need is to base64url encode the hash value itself (not the hex string representation of it)

Comment: What you got is probably the same as the result of the online hashing tool in the linked answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article. To me, it looks like i did the same thing like:
var base64Signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(base64Header + "." + base64Payload , secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64).replace(/\+/g,'-').replace(/\=+$/m,'');

by adding utl_encode.base64_encode around the function to create the hash value. Except it is not an url encoding function. I don't know how to create this in oracle pl/sql.

Comment: to get base64url you just need to replace `+` with `-`, `/` with `_` and cut the pasdding `=`, simple string replace. I can't test you pl/sql code, but maybe you can try the code snippet from the linked answer and insert you hash in place where the code converts the online calcualted hash, just to see if this works.

Comment: I just tried the line `var base64hash = new Buffer.from("49F94AC7044948C78A285D904F87F0A4C7897F7E8F3A4EB2255FDA750B2CC397", 'hex').toString('base64').replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-').replace(/\=+$/m,'')` in node.js and got the desired result: `SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c`. So it's exactly what I thought, your result is a hex string representation of the hash, but you need the numerical value, before you continue with base64url conversion.

Comment: @jps Thanks very much, this helped us a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the final solution with help from jps:

```
function cleanup_base64 (p_base in raw) return varchar2
    is
            l_return varchar2(32767);
            l_crlf   varchar2(2) := chr(13) || chr(10);
            l_base   varchar2(32767);
    begin
            l_base   := utl_i18n.raw_to_char (p_base, CONVERT_CHARSET);
            l_base   := replace(replace(replace(replace(l_base,l_crlf), '='),'+', '-'), '/', '_');
            l_return := l_base;

            return l_return;
    end;


 function generate_jitsi_token (p_naam in varchar2) return varchar2
    is

        l_token             varchar2(30000);
        l_header            varchar2(30000);
        l_payload           varchar2(30000);
        l_signature         varchar2(30000);
        l_secretkey         varchar2(10000):="your-secret-key";

        l_content           varchar2(30000);
        l_pay_clean         varchar2(30000);
        l_hdr_clean         varchar2(30000);

        l_header_base64     raw(30000);
        l_payload_base64    raw(30000);
        l_signature_base64  raw(30000);

    begin


        -- maak header middels json en base64 encode
        select json_object ('alg'  value 'HS256'
                           ,'typ'  value 'JWT')
        into   l_header
        from dual;

        -- maak payload middels json en base64 encode
        select json_object ('context' value
                    json_object ('user' value
                         json_object ('name' value p_naam))
                           ,'sub'  value 'text'
                           ,'iss'  value 'text'
                           ,'room' value '*'
                           ,'aud'  value 'jitsi')
        into   l_payload
        from dual;

        --
        l_header_base64  := utl_encode.base64_encode (utl_i18n.string_to_raw (l_header,  CONVERT_CHARSET));
        l_payload_base64 := utl_encode.base64_encode (utl_i18n.string_to_raw (l_payload, CONVERT_CHARSET));

        l_hdr_clean := cleanup_base64 (l_header_base64);
        l_pay_clean := cleanup_base64 (l_payload_base64);

        l_content := l_hdr_clean || '.' ||l_pay_clean;

        l_signature_base64  := utl_encode.base64_encode
                                      (dbms_crypto.mac(utl_i18n.string_to_raw (l_content, CONVERT_CHARSET)
                                                      ,dbms_crypto.hmac_sh256
                                                      ,utl_i18n.string_to_raw(l_secretkey, CONVERT_CHARSET)));

        l_signature :=  cleanup_base64 (l_signature_base64);
        l_token := l_hdr_clean||'.'||l_pay_clean||'.'|| l_signature;


        return l_token;
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like that

Oracle PL/SQL Server Side Implementation Example for User Authentication via JWT:

```
1. Create a table to store JWT tokens:
    
     CREATE TABLE jwt_tokens (
       token VARCHAR2(4000) PRIMARY KEY,
       user_id NUMBER,
       expiration_date DATE
     );
    
     2. Creating a procedure for generating a JWT token:
    
     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE generate_jwt_token(
       p_user_id IN NUMBER,
       p_expiration_date IN DATE,
       p_secret_key IN VARCHAR2,
       p_token OUT VARCHAR2
     ) AS
       l_header VARCHAR2(4000);
       l_payload VARCHAR2(4000);
       l_signature VARCHAR2(4000);
     BEGIN
       -- Create a JWT header
       l_header := '{"alg":"HS256","type":"JWT"}';
    
       -- Create JWT body
       l_payload := '{"user_id":' || p_user_id || ',"exp":' || p_expiration_date || '}';
    
       -- Create a JWT signature
       l_signature := dbms_crypto.mac(
         utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_header || '.' || l_payload),
         dbms_crypto.hmac_sh256,
         utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_secret_key)
       );
    
       -- JWT encoding
       p_token := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(
         utl_encode.base64_encode(
           utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_header) || '.' ||
           utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_payload) || '.' ||
           utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_signature)
         )
       );
     END;
    
     3. Create a function to validate the JWT token:
    
     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verify_jwt_token(
       p_token IN VARCHAR2,
       p_secret_key IN VARCHAR2
     ) RETURN NUMBER AS
       l_header VARCHAR2(4000);
       l_payload VARCHAR2(4000);
       l_signature VARCHAR2(4000);
       l_user_id NUMBER;
       l_expiration_date DATE;
     BEGIN
       -- JWT decoding
       l_header := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(
         utl_encode.base64_decode(
           utl_raw.cast_to_raw(regexp_substr(p_token, '^[^\.]+'))
         )
       );
       l_payload := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(
         utl_encode.base64_decode(
           utl_raw.cast_to_raw(regexp_substr(p_token, '\.[^\.]+\.')))
       );
       l_signature := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(
         utl_encode.base64_decode(
           utl_raw.cast_to_raw(regexp_substr(p_token, '\.[^\.]+$'))
         )
       );
    
       -- JWT signature verification
       IF dbms_crypto.mac(
         utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_header || '.' || l_payload),
         dbms_crypto.hmac_sh256,
         utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_secret_key)
       ) <> utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_signature) THEN
         RETURN NULL;
       END IF;
    
       -- JWT expiration check
       SELECT user_id, expiration_date INTO l_user_id, l_expiration_date
       FROM jwt_tokens
       WHERE token = p_token;
    
       IF l_expiration_date < SYSDATE THEN
         RETURN NULL;
       END IF;
    
       RETURN l_user_id;
     END;
    
     4. Create a procedure to save the JWT token in the database:
    
     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE save_jwt_token(
       p_token IN VARCHAR2,
       p_user_id IN NUMBER,
       p_expiration_date IN DATE
     ) AS
     BEGIN
       INSERT INTO jwt_tokens(token, user_id, expiration_date)
       VALUES(p_token, p_user_id, p_expiration_date);
     END;
    
     5. An example of using procedures and functions for user authentication through JWT:
    
     DECLARE
       l_token VARCHAR2(4000);
       l_user_id NUMBER;
     BEGIN
       -- JWT token generation
       generate_jwt_token(123, SYSDATE + 1, 'secret_key', l_token);
    
       -- Saving the JWT token in the database
       save_jwt_token(l_token, 123, SYSDATE + 1);
    
       -- JWT token validation
       l_user_id := verify_jwt_token(l_token, 'secret_key');
    
       IF l_user_id IS NULL THEN
         dbms_output. put_line('Invalid token');
       ELSE
         dbms_output.put_line('User ID: ' || l_user_id);
       END IF;
     END;
```